# Mathematics of computation

Tags: reference-request, computer-science

What is a good introduction to turing machines, complexity classes, P=NP etc from a purely mathematical viewpoint?
I want to know how computation relates to provability in mathematics, I need the details of how one relates arithemtical statements to turing machines.
I am not interested in practical computing or programming.
Also I want to know how to prove that some system is turing complete.

Comment: Maybe this question is too broad, in which caase eliminate complexity classes and P=np from above. But I would like a general overview of mathematics of computation aswell.

Answer (score 6):

You might try Michael Sipser's [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534950973).

Comment: Sipser's book is more focused on CS, and uses some nonstandard terminology like "mapping reducibility". It's not a bad book, but I would recommend something else for someone interested in mathematics.

Comment: Sipser's book is an excellent read if you ever plan on writing a textbook; it is the best mathematics textbook I have ever read, and I would maintain this even if you convinced me that it isn't a mathematics textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Try *Computational Complexity* by Papadimitriou.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start for the relationship between computability and provability is *Computability and Logic* by Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey. But it's not for the faint of heart - the content is dense, and the book has a lot more content than its thickness suggests.

For something more CS focused that will discuss Turing completeness and complexity, another great text is *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation* by Hopcroft and Ullman. Just skip chapters 2-7 which cover regular and context-free languages. Again, this book has a lot of content and is very well regarded.

Comment: +1 I'm reading Hopcroft's book right now and it's extremely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Another very good book is Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach, by Sanjeev Arora. See http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/. It is a very good book and not very expensive compared to Sipser's and Papadimitriou's book. The topics of the book cover a variety of topics in complexity theory. 
Also, there is a draft online, so you can check that if you want to see how the book is like.